# finding the periods of miniships in the Burning Ship

Tags: recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics, fractals, complex-dynamics

The [Burning Ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Ship_fractal) fractal is similar to the Mandelbrot set, only instead of being defined by a complex quadratic polynomial, it can defined by two real functions:
$$\begin{aligned}X &\leftarrow X^2 - Y^2 + A \\ Y &\leftarrow 2|XY| + B\end{aligned}$$

Similarly to the Mandelbrot set, which contains smaller copies of itself adorned with filaments, the Burning Ship fractal contains smaller miniships.  These occur due to renormalization, where a periodic cycle exhibits dynamics over one period similar to the main body of the set over one iteration.

**The question is, given a simple region in the complex plane (something like a square or a circle), what is the period of the lowest-period miniship contained within the region?**

Bonus points for methods that are applicable to a more general class of fractals, not just the quadratic Burning Ship.

For the quadratic Mandelbrot set I know two methods, one using the Jordan curve theorem iterating the corners of a polygon until it surrounds the origin, the first iteration at which that happens is the period; the other uses Taylor series ball arithmetic, which I don't fully understand, but is better than naive ball arithmetic.  Implementations can be found here: [box](https://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-numerics/blob/f519b65e15697e8f473f2304d427d49f34f7da8e:/c/lib/m_d_box_period.c), [ball](https://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-numerics/blob/f519b65e15697e8f473f2304d427d49f34f7da8e:/c/lib/m_d_ball_period.c). I believe neither can be applied to the Burning Ship because its functions aren't well behaved enough.

I have attempted to use ball arithmetic (midpoint-radius intervals, one real ball each for $X$ and $Y$) to solve this problem, but failed miserably - it more easily finds nearby "outer" miniships outside the region visible at shallower zoom levels than "inner" ones within the region at deeper zoom levels. One has to zoom in a great deal further to reduce the region of interest, before it finds the desired period.  **Perhaps my lack of special treatment of $|\cdot|$ and $\cdot^2$ was to blame?** (I followed the simple [abs from arblib](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/arb/blob/ecb70e7476da079b949acfeb4894c543cf850ad7/arb/abs.c), and used regular multiplication, which is also used in arblib as far as I can tell.)

I have also attempted to use the box method, simply continuing in the cases where the polygon gets folded when it crosses an axis (this may lead to a higher or lower period than the true one being found by the algorithm).  It seems to work a lot better than the ball arithmetic, though I'm concerned about the folding...

My end goal is an implementation in a fractal browser for accelerating interesting zoom navigation techniques; I already have implemented Newton's root finding method and miniship size estimates, both of which need the period as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding *iterating the corners of a polygon until it surrounds the origin*, I received a reply via email from Robert Munafo:

> This is indeed true, so long as your mapping is a continuous mapping; this preserves the topology of the closed loop (i.e. polygon) and ensures that you'll surround the forward-image of the origin if and only if you've iterated $p$ times where $p$ is the period. Burning Ship is defined in terms of the absolute value $f=|x|$ as well as several more familiar continuous functions, so the whole thing is continuous.

So the *Jordan curve theorem* method works for continuous formulas, with the caveat that folding and other non-linearities may need the polygon to be subdivided (for example when an edge crosses an axis and would be folded/bent by $|\cdot|$) so that the topology remains the same.